# How to post image in twitter iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i want to integrate twitter.I also want to upload images through this twitter.Is there any open source for posting the images through twitter in iphone app.Can any one help me this issue.

Comment: You can use twitpic to upload pictures to twitter

Comment: aman thanks.Is there any opensource code using that

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2010/02/2-approaches-to-twitpic-integration/) and official [documentation](http://twitpic.com/api.do#uploadAndPost)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 will have full twitter support. I take it you are programming in iOS4 SDK still. it might be with looking at the iOS5 developer docs

Just a Thought

GC